# How to make a Django Model form Readonly?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django form name "SampleForm". Which i use to take input from user. Now i want to use same form to show this information to user on a different page. But form is editable I want to make the form read only. Is there any way to make whole form Readonly ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pseudo-code (not tested):

```
class ReadOnlyFormMixin(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in self.fields.keys():
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do not do anything
        pass

class SampleReadOnlyForm(ReadOnlyFormMixin, SampleForm):
    pass
```

Comment: Thats a good ans as same frm was used to edit the information.

Comment: If you are using Django>=1.9, you can use self.fields[key].disabled = True https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Comment: A sidenote for @JoeJ's comment. If in some case, you only want to lock a part of the form – the fields will not be present in the form data if they are `disabled`. (i.e. if someone wants the field data to be posted making it `readonly` is still an option).

Comment: With this anyone can just edit the field in the browser and post it. Any idea how it can be restricted even on the backend if someone edits the HTML in the browser and submits the form?

Answer (score 1):

```
class SampleForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            for field in self.fields.keys():
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Just this should make the entire form readonly whenever an instance is available for the form.

Comment: This would not prevent POST hacks tho so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

```
class ReadOnlySampleForm(SampleForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for key in self.fields.keys():
        self.fields[key].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Answer (score -1):

in Django 4.1, override the get_context_data with

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(object_list=None, **kwargs)

    form = AddressForm(instance=self.get_object())
    for name, field in form.fields.items():
        field.disabled = True
    context["form"] = form
    return context
```