# How to reuse Django forms

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I want to reuse Django forms in following scenario:

1. Make all form fields "read-only" while displaying
2. Use the same form to get data while editing

I've used the below function to make the field read-only while displaying the data:

```
class form1(modelForm):
    fields...
    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in self.fields.keys():
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

I also tried using the **init** function, but while editing I am unable to use "form1", Django still renders the form as read-only.

A little help on how to achieve would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `get_form` calls `__init__` of the base class? What are you doing there?

Comment: Making the form fields readonly, Please advice on an effective way doing this, if I am wrong, I got this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248575/how-to-make-a-django-model-form-readonly

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a full service solution provider. Did you understand the code you have been copying?

Comment: Sorry, I regret I just copied, thanks for highlighting, I now understood and achieved it 

Lesson learnt

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can add and accept an answer yourself which will help anyone who comes across this in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution goes like this

```
form_to_edit(modelForm):
    fields
    .
    .

form_to_display(form_to_edit):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(form_to_edit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for key in self.fields.keys():
        self.fields[key].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Whenever the form has to be just displayed, render "form_to_display" and for edit, render "form_to_edit",

The code in form_to_display creates/initializes form_to_edit with readonly fields